# video playing from pdf file in iphone or ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an application, which is reads a PDF file and displays it in webview now we have videos embedded within pdf, how to play those videos within webview like html5 did.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help on this please. any suggestions or any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Webview will not detect and play the videos embedded inside the pdf. You have to parse the pdf   and get the file stream and play it using MPMoviePlayerController.